# Inserting a value into an ordered tree in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, insert, tree

Basically I have defined a Tree data type which is defined as follows:

```
data Tree a = Empty
| Leaf a
| Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Now I have to create a function to insert a value into an ordered tree (it doesn't have to sort the tree, just add the value). This is what I've come up with so far:

```
insert :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x Empty      = Leaf x
insert x (Leaf m)   | m < x     = Node (Leaf x) m Empty
                    | otherwise = Node Empty m (Leaf x)
insert x (Node l m r)   | x > m     = Node (Leaf l) m (insert x r)
                        | otherwise = Node (insert x l) m (Leaf r)
```

However, when I run this I get the following error message:

> Couldn't match expected type 'a' (a rigid variable)
>              against inferred type 'Tree a'
>       'a' is bound by the type signature for 'insert' at Main.hs:11:10
>       In the first argument of 'Leaf', namely 'l'
>       In the first argument of 'Node', namely '(Leaf l)'
>       In the expression: Node (Leaf l) m (insert x r)

I assume it's something to do with types but I can't see where I've put any types that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Translating roughly from type-checker-ese into English:

> Couldn't match expected type 'a' (a
>   rigid variable)

This means that it was expecting an arbitrary type `a`, that's also used elsewhere (hence "rigid") so it can't just take any old type.

> against inferred type 'Tree a'

This means that instead it found a `Tree` containing elements of the expected rigid polymorphic type. This obviously doesn't make sense, so it complains.

> 'a' is bound by the type signature for 'insert' at Main.hs:11:10

This just says that the type is being restricted because you specified it in that type signature.

> In the first argument of 'Leaf', namely 'l' In the first
>   argument of 'Node', namely '(Leaf l)' In the expression: Node (Leaf l) m (insert x r)

This is just telling you which specific term it's complaining about, with some context.

So, to sort things out: The variable `l` is a `Tree a` being used in a context that needs just `a`. In this case `l` obviously has the correct type, so the mistake is in how it's used. Why was the type checker looking for type `a`? Because you applied a `Tree` data constructor to it. But wait, `l` is already a `Tree a`! *et voila*, the scales fall from our eyes and the truth is beheld.

...which was all just a lengthy way of explaining why **Edward Kmett**'s quick-draw answer is correct, and what kind of reasoning one might use to arrive at such an answer.

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". Great answer!

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is that

```
insert x (Node l m r)   | x > m     = Node (Leaf l) m (insert x r)
                        | otherwise = Node (insert x l) m (Leaf r)
```

should probably be

```
insert x (Node l m r)   | x > m     = Node l m (insert x r)
                        | otherwise = Node (insert x l) m r
```

because `l` and `r` are already Trees.

Answer (score 2):

`l` is the first parameter of `Node` and so it is of type `Tree a` (the whole left subtree). `Leaf` on the other hand just takes a single value as a parameter, not a whole tree. Therefore `Leaf l` gives a type error, since it tries to make a Leaf out of a whole tree. Probably you simply wanted `l` instead of `Leaf l` in this place.

Also, what is the difference between `Leaf x` and `Node Empty x Empty`? Are you sure you need both constructors?

Comment: benwad may also want to think about the behavior of inserting a value that is already in the tree. In the above code, what is the difference when a value is already present in the Tree in a Leaf, vs. if it is present in a Node?